# Remove orange highlight on tap for android browser

Tags: android, html, css

A Link(checkbox) is highlighted by orange color when user tap on it on android browser. I would like to remove this highlight. Couple answers was found but they are don't work in my case for some reason. As I understood following css must solve the problem, but highlight still appears,

```
*{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Although it is not a good practice have you tried using `!important` along with your CSS rule ? If it will work with `!important` it means that something is overriding it.

Comment: have you tried with `* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}`

Comment: Have you tried this one?

    `element, element:focus, element:active { outline:none; }`

Comment: @Yup, transparent works only on IOs

Comment: @Fallup, yes I tried !important - no luck

Comment: @SurjithSM, Yes, I tried it also for element and :focus, I will try for :active, but don't think that it will help

Comment: It is really strange. You can try to debug it from desktop with Chrome dev tools -> Advanced -> Override user agent -> Choose some Android based user agent and check applied styles. See [Remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code..

```
*{outline:none;}"
```

Good luck..

Comment: I wish that it to be so easy, but no, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you check again with *{outline:none; border:0;} may be work..?